# Bad Request trying to call getMedia() on DocsService

Tags: java, google-docs, google-docs-api

When calling getMedia() on DocsService for some document I got next message:
Bad Request
We have encountered an error, which we will investigate immediately. Sorry for the inconvenience.

This happens already 10 days, how this one could be fixed ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you retry?

The Google infrastructure regularly throws 500 errors which succeed after a retry. Make sure you do an exponential backoff.

Comment: I'm trying to get this document for about 10 days, each time there 5 retries - no luck.